# Error Deploying mule in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mule

HI I am trying to deploy Mule in tomcat Web-App
I am using maven to genarate the war file
MY flow xml is----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
  <flow name="safwsread" doc:name="safread">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="data" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <component class="com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.MasterCRMApex.ClientCall" doc:name="Java">
            <method-entry-point-resolver> 
                <include-entry-point method="getsfData"/> 
            </method-entry-point-resolver>
        </component>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>


    <flow name="safwswrite" doc:name="safwrite">
        <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" moveToDirectory="D:/Test/Moved" path="D:/Test/Input">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
      <component  doc:name="Java" class="com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall">
        <method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="setsfData"/>
    </method-entry-point-resolver>
      </component>
        <logger message="DONE~!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I am getting this error,can anyone help me with this---

```
 19:25:56,224 INFO   - Initialising connector: connector.http.mule.default
    19:25:56,360 INFO   - Initialising flow: safwsread
    19:25:56,360 INFO   - Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@55c4a3
    19:25:56,393 INFO   - Initialising service: safwsread.stage1
    19:25:56,430 INFO   - Initialising component: component.10632627
    19:25:56,498 INFO   - Initialising connector: connector.file.mule.default
    19:25:56,520 INFO   - Disposing flow: safwsread
    19:25:56,521 INFO   - Disposing service: safwsread.stage1
    19:25:56,522 INFO   - Disposing component: component.10632627
    19:25:56,523 INFO   - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c1497a: defining beans [_muleCustomEditorConfigurer,_muleObjectNameProcessor,_mulePropertyPlaceholderProcessor,_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap,_muleNotificationManager,_muleAnnotationsProcessor,_muleTransformerAnnotationProcessor,_muleConfiguration,._muleNotificationManager:notification.1,._muleNotificationManager:notification.2,._muleNotificationManager:notification.3,._muleNotificationManager:notification.4,._muleNotificationManager:notification.5,._muleNotificationManager:notification.6,._muleNotificationManager:notification.7,._muleNotificationManager:notification.8,._muleNotificationManager:notification.9,._muleNotificationManager:notification.10,_muleSystemModel,_defaultInMemoryQueueStore,_defaultPersistentQueueStore,_defaultInMemoryObjectStore,_defaultPersistentObjectStore,_defaultUserObjectStore,_defaultTransientUserObjectStore,_muleQueueManager,_muleObjectStoreManager,_muleSecurityManager,_muleMessageProcessingManager,_muleProperties,_muleEndpointFactory,_muleStreamCloserService,_defaultThreadingProfile,_converterResolver,_defaultMessageDispatcherThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageRequesterThreadingProfile,_defaultMessageReceiverThreadingProfile,_defaultServiceThreadingProfile,_defaultRetryPolicyTemplate,_muleExpressionLanguage,_muleLockFactory,_muleLockProvider,_muleProcessingTimeWatcher,safwsread,.safwsread:inbound-endpoint.11,.safwsread:component.12,.safwsread:component.12:method-entry-point-resolver.13,.safwsread:object-to-json-transformer.14,safwswrite,.safwswrite:inbound-endpoint.15,.safwswrite:inbound-endpoint.15:filename-regex-filter.16,.safwswrite:component.17,.safwswrite:component.17:method-entry-point-resolver.18,.safwswrite:logger.19]; root of factory hierarchy
    19:25:56,523 INFO   - Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
    org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'safwswrite': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.component.DefaultJavaComponent] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.object.PrototypeObjectFactory] while setting bean property 'objectFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:59)
        at com.trng.MuleHelper.HelperClass.startup(HelperClass.java:25)
        at com.trng.Servlets.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:35)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'safwswrite': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.component.DefaultJavaComponent] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.object.PrototypeObjectFactory] while setting bean property 'objectFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall
        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:117)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'safwswrite': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.component.DefaultJavaComponent] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.object.PrototypeObjectFactory] while setting bean property 'objectFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.object.PrototypeObjectFactory] while setting bean property 'objectFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1427)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'objectClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
        ... 56 more
    Aug 04, 2014 7:25:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ControllerServlet] in context with path [/MuleJsp] threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.trng.MuleHelper.HelperClass.startup(HelperClass.java:35)
        at com.trng.Servlets.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:35)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

is there any problem with the xml or any jars need to be add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.schemas._class.CRMReporting.ClientCall
```

It seems you're not packaging all the necessary classes in your WAR file.